# How to return both integer parameter and render template as response in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony, render

I want to return on my ajax request rendered view, and some integer values, but I dont know how I can do this. I try to encode array with content into json, but then in success callback function I getting the array where I can see the field with integer, and "header" param that empty. So how can I return both integer parameter and render response in Symfony2 ?

Comment: Have you considered using session.

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from your question that you are wanting to return something like..

```
array(
    'html'      => **your html**,
    'integer'   => **your integer**,
);
```

If that is correct you could do the following...

```
// ->renderResponse render the string and creates a response object for you to return
// ->render just renders the string into a variable
$html = $this->container->get('templating')->render(**template**, **parameters**);
$integer = **your integer**;

// Return a JSON object with the correct headers and what not
return new JsonResponse::create(array(
    'html'      => $html,
    'integer'   => $integer,
));
```

Comment: I solve this by using renderView instead of render... but thanks!)

Comment: I assume you used `$this->renderView()` in the controller? That is a shortcut for `$this->container->get('templating')->render()` (https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Controller/Controller.php#L151-L162).